# How to obtain the application showed in mobile foregroung?

Tags: android, service

I'd like to know which activity display on current mobile phone's interface in a service.

There is activity stack in android. Is it has a global activity stack in system and supply the activity information showed on foreground?

Answer (score 2):

```
Context context = null; // FIXME: init with your context.
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
            if (procInfos.get(i).importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                //the current running process
                Log.d("FOREGROUND_Application", procInfos.get(i).processName + "is running on the FOREGROUND");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow, didn't even know this was possible